# How to check if a Perl hash is defined when it doesn't have any key/value pairs

Tags: perl, hash

I'm trying to figure out a way to check if a hash has been declared in a Perl script while inside a module function.

Given the following script (file *script.pl*):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use checkHash;

our %testHash = ("key"=>"value");

print &checkHash() ? 1 : 0;
```

Along with this module (*checkHash.pm*);

```
sub checkHash {
    if(%main::testHash) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

1;
```

Running on a Mac with [OS X v10.6.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard) and Perl v5.10.0, the return value of checkHash is "1" which I would expect. However, if I remove the key value pair from the script by changing the line:

```
our %testHash = ("key"=>"value");
```

to:

```
our %testHash = ();
```

The return value is "0". My original assumption was that this would be "1", but after reading about the way the test I'm using is testing for the size in the hash, I see why that was incorrect thinking.

**Is there a test that can be used in the checkHash module that will return true if the hash it's testing exists, but doesn't have any keys assigned to it?**

Comment: Why? What are you *really* trying to accomplish? I am asking because, all my life, I never faced a situation a test like this was needed.

Comment: I'm building a little framework module that sets up some basic logging, debugging and other common functions. I'm planning to use a hash defined with "our" in the main script to pass a few pieces of info back and forth to the framework module. When I'm bootstrapping the framework, I wanted to put in a check to make sure the hash existed. That's where the question started from. Since the main script would only define the hash, but no values, I couldn't figure it out. (Note: I'm now looking at calling a bootstrap to populate the hash, but I'd still like to know the answer to this question).

Comment: The answer to your question is a question:  What do you think "defined" means?  It sounds like you think it means the same thing as "declared".  It doesn't.

Comment: @darch - Yep. I was basically thinking "defined" and "declared" were the same thing. I was trying to write around that, but obviously, that was creating confusion. I'm going to update the question to help address that for anyone who hits this in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing whether a given symbol has been declared is almost certainly useless and a desire to perform it is indicative of a design problem.  For the sake of completeness, however, here's tests for both lexical and dynamic symbols:

Find out if the lexical symbol `$whoopee` has been declared:

```
use Try::Tiny;
my $declared = try { use strict; $whoopee; 1 };
```

Find out if any dynamic symbol called `FooPackage::whoopee` has been declared (including hashes that spell their names `%FooPackage::whoopee`):

```
my $declared = exists $FooPackage::{whoopee};
```

Comment: You're correct. I wasn't wording my question well at all. The goal was to see if a hash had been declared. I've updated the question to try to clarify that. Incidentally, by changing from "if(%main::testHash)" to "if(exists $main::{testHash})" I get the behavior I was expecting. As I'm relatively new to making my own modules a design problem is pretty likely. In fact, I changed the approach I was using when I ran into this, but it's nice to know there is an answer that works.

Answer (score 5):

defined() is not a meaningful test on aggregates (arrays and hashes).  [perldoc -f defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) has this to say:

> Use of "defined" on aggregates (hashes and arrays) is deprecated.  It
>   used to report whether memory for that aggregate has ever been
>   allocated.
>                  This behavior may disappear in future versions of Perl.
>   You should instead use a simple test for size:
>
> ```
>                if (@an_array) { print "has array elements\n" }
>                if (%a_hash)   { print "has hash members\n"   }
> ```

Comment: The problem with that test is that when there are no members in the hash, it still shows up as false when I test it. Even though the hash itself hash been setup with "my %testHash" or "our %testHash". I'm trying to figure out a way I can safely check to see if the hash already exists before assigning a new key/value to it, but so far have only been able to get that test to work if there is already at least one key/value pair.

Comment: That's the point: "the hash already exists" is a meaningless test.  Variables exist when you need them to, or under strict, for lexicals or unqualified package variables, when you've declared them.  There should be no need to do what you are trying to.

Comment: I wasn't asking this well, but didn't realize it until I started getting answers. I've updated the question to try to ask it better. The test I really wanted was in the module itself. The idea being that a little framework module I'm writing could use a shared hash to communicate with its main script. The framework would check to make sure the hash was declared (not defined, which is where I created a lot of confusion) and available before attempting to use it. I haven't done that much of work building framework modules, so this may be way off base, but it seemed to make sense.

Comment: So what would be the harm if it didn't check that it was declared?

Comment: One example is the debug flag. The bootstrap function I call in the framework does command line argument processing with Getopt::Long and checks for "--debug". If that flag is set, it updates the main scripts %c hash (which I use for config/communication) to true, otherwise, it sets it to false. a was trying to avoid setting the flag if the hash didn't exist to avoid throwing warnings. (Some of the framework functions could be used without having to call the bootstarp, so there's no guarantee that I would have set that has. Though, in practice that's unlikely.)

Comment: Incidentally, the way that I'm doing it now is to set the hash with the bootstrap so it's set explicitly. (i.e. instead of "our %c = (); &bootstrap();" I'm using "our %c = bootstrap();". So, in this case, I no longer have to do that specific check, but it's still nice to know how to do it in case I need it for some other craziness in the future.

Comment: but setting the flag in the hash *makes* it exist, with no warning: `$main::c{'debug'} = 1;`

Comment: Ahhhh Ha! I didn't realize that would work. I'm so used to using warnings and strict in the main script that it never occurred to me to even try that. I would have assumed perl would have complained about it and since strict was in effect. You just expended my knowledge about how that works. Very cool and very much appreciated.

Comment: strict intentionally does not apply to fully qualified variables, for just such situations as yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can just count the keys:

```
sub checkHash {
    return ( scalar keys %main::testHash ) ? 1 : 0;
}

perl -le 'my %h; print ( scalar keys %h ) ? 1 : 0;'
0
perl -le 'my %h = (foo=>1); print ( scalar keys %h ) ? 1 : 0;'
1
```

Comment: Looks like you reversed the colon and the question mark(i.e. should be "return (scalar keys %main::testHash) ? 1 : 0;"). However, this doesn't help since there aren't any keys to count. It still returns false.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. It does work though; I added an example. ysth's is better and what I probably would have done.

Comment: One more catch, looks like an extra "=>1)" made it into the first example. Something like "perl -le 'my %h; print ( scalar keys %h ) ? 1 : 0;'". The trick that I'm looking for is a way to do that test, but get it to return 1 instead of 0. As it is, when there are no keys in %h, you get the same result if you don't even declare it (e.g. perl -le 'print ( scalar keys %h ) ? 1 : 0;'). I'm looking for a test that will show me that will return true even when no keys exist. (I should probably be saying "initialized" instead of "defined" to avoid confusion, but that just occurred to me.

Answer (score 1):

See [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values)

> If you evaluate a hash in scalar context, it returns false if the hash is empty. If there are any key/value pairs, it returns true; more precisely, the value returned is a string consisting of the number of used buckets and the number of allocated buckets, separated by a slash.

That explains why your `defined` test seemed to work.